# Resetting height of an HTML element via CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I use a custom-built asp.net control that renders to a DIV and has "height='0'" hard-coded into the element (I know.. stupid).  But I need to reset it - get rid of the height assignment somehow.  Is this doable with CSS?

I can set the height to 100px for example, and it works.  But that's not what I want - I want the height assignment removed pretty much.

UPDATE:
Using FireBug, I can see that CSS's height gets overridden by the hard-coded one:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

I guess there's no way for me to resolve this besides removing the hard-coded height=0.  Anyone else see an alternative?

Comment: Your image link seems to have broken, so we *can't* see what's happening there. If you still have the original screenshot, please reupload it to stack.imgur, or just edit your question to remove the broken image. Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You might well need to use `height:auto !important` because the height attribute has a very high priority (IIRC).

But ideally you would karate-kick that attribute out of there. Yuck.

Comment: Perfect! Very useful if you are using responsive design!

Answer (score 6):

change the height to 'auto' and see if that works for you.

Auto is the default height for elements, it means the browser calculates the height itself.

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute always overrides class. So you're going to have to remove the height rule of the style attribute.

Comment: It's a height attribute, not a style attribute.

Comment: Rahul is actually correct - it's the property of the style attribute in this case.